# Laravel error:After installing laravel I get the following message

Tags: laravel

After installing laravel I get the following message when run the project:

```
 Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
```

Comment: Take a look at the logs (`app/storage/logs/laravel.log`) or enable debugging in `app/config/app.php` to get a detailed error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at your laravel log, located at `app/storage/logs/laravel.log`.

Whilst your application is in development mode, you can make your life a lot easier by enabling detailed error reporting. Just change false to true here:

[image]

In this file (app/config/app.php)  - first line:

[image]

Nobody will be able to help you with above posted error message, but it will be very easy to help yourself with detailed error reporting enabled

Answer (score 1):

Set 'debug' to true in app/config/app.php.
If it's already to true, set it to false, refresh, then set it again to true.